# CSS/JS conflict in order of precedence

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a darkmode toggle css/js plugin on my wordpress blog; it's been working fine until this morning when it suddenly disappeared from view. The functionality is still there, and the HTML is being rendered by the browser, so I'm thought it might be a conflict in my order of precedence of my css/js files in my header & footer.php files? Any help would be greatly appreciated. the files I'm referring to are:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/dark-mode.css">`

`<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/dark-mode-switch.min.js"></script>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/animations.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/lightbox.min.css">
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/7f9785fbd6.js"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/purecookie.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/dark-mode.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/intlTelInput.css"> 
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baskervville:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bodoni+Moda:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css"/>
```

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/css3-animate-it.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/dark-mode-switch.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/purecookie.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask on [wordpress.se]?

Comment: I'll do that too, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by *"it suddenly disappeared from view"*? You said *"the functionality is still there, and the HTML is being rendered by the browse"* so if the functionality is there and the code is there, isn't it working? If not, have you checked the browser's console?

Comment: I can see where the toggle is in the rendered HTML, and can trigger the toggle by clicking where the it _should_ be, but unfortunately can't _see_ it, if that makes sense. Sorry, I should have been clearer.